# Send mail whenever the log is cleared in Magento

Tags: php, magento, email, logging

In Magento, whenever logs are cleared, I want to get an email message with their original contents. I want `system.log` and `exception.log`, as well as DB log (tables `log_quote`, `log_url`, `log_visitor_info`, `log_visitor`, `log_url_info` and `log_customer`). The message should contain a text file for each of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can get notification mail for log cleaning by enabling *admin → System → Configuration → Advanced → system → Log cleaning*. Here you can add your email address to get the notification. But the messages contain only a notification, not the log files. For this you have to build a custom module.